# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: list, react-redux, redux-toolkit, readonly

I am trying to use reduxjs/toolkit for to create reducer as the following. However, when I try to dispatch the `removeFavorite` I get the following error  `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.` the payload is just the index of the object that I am trying to remove.

```js
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  favorites: [],
};

const favoriteSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'favorites',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleFavorite(state, action) {
      state.favorites.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeFavorite(state, action) {
      state.favorites.splice(action.payload, 1);
    },
    setFavoritesToFetchData(state, action) {
      state.favorites = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {toggleFavorite, removeFavorite, setFavoritesToFetchData} =
  favoriteSlice.actions;
export default favoriteSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: state.favorites.splice(action.payload, 1);

Comment: in state.favorites.splice(action.payload, 1); .. is action.payload is holding the index of the element you want to remove? 

consider adding your code in sand box and share the link to help you solve error faster